# What class does an instance of IHost returned by HostBuilder.Build() belong to?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft.extensions.hosting

I'm learning about Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting, and I've come across the HostBuilder.Build() method. I can see that it returns an instance of IHost interface ('an initialise IHost', according to learn.microsoft.com), but I don't know what class this instance object is a type of. Doesn't this object need to belong to a class that implements the IHost interface?

Answer (score 3):

> Doesn't this object need to belong to a class that implements the IHost interface?

Yes, `HostBuilder.Build()` returns an instance of class implementing the `IHost` interface, but the class itself can be an internal one ([for example](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/IHost.cs,3bdbcb83576750f8,references)).

You can get the actual type name by calling `GetType().FullName` on the returned instance but in general you should not care about underlying implementation that much.